# how to drop row with certain condition

Tags: python, dataframe, automation, drop

I really need your help here, I am doing comparasion of two dataframes,I want to drop the row where has no difference between 'old'and 'new'cols so that I dont need to filter them to make the change afterwards, this is just a test, real excel file has thounds of rows.Thanks you in advance.Please forgive me for being so dense with code, if something is not clear please ask me and correct and explain.

**Dataframe old**

| N_Compte | Nom | Adresse | Ville | Code_postal | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1RUE | PARIS | 75001 | old |
| 2 | B | 2RUE | LYON8 | 69008 | old |
| 3 | C | 13RUE | REIMS | 51100 | old |
| 4 | D | 4RUE | NICE | 6000 | old |

**Dataframe new**

| N_Compte | Nom | Adresse | Ville | Code_postal | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 11rue | PARIS | 75001 | new |
| 2 | B | 12rue | NICE | 6000 | new |
| 3 | C | 13RUE | REIMS | 51100 | new |
| 5 | E | 5rue | LILLE | 36788 | new |

**Explaination for my codes**

First is a structural comparison of the two dataframes

Then comes the comparison of the content

Finally the content that has been changed needs to be displayed and be highlighted, but the ones that have not been changed are dropped out.

if the old and new are the same then the whole row is deleted, if the old and new columns are not the same then the difference need to be save in new excel in new sheet

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
old=pd.read_excel(io=r'old.xlsx',sheet_name='Feuil1', na_values=['NA'])
new=pd.read_excel(io=r'new.lsx', sheet_name='Feuil1', na_values=['NA'])
old['version'] = "old"
new['version'] = "new"
old_comptetotal=set(old['N_Compte'])
new_comptetotal=set(new['N_Compte'])
suppr_compte=old_comptetotal-new_comptetotal
ajoute_compte=new_comptetotal-old_comptetotal
print(suppr_compte)
print(ajoute_compte)
all_data=pd.concat([old,new],ignore_index=True)
changes=all_data.drop_duplicates(subset=old.columns,keep='last')
print(changes)
cpt_double=changes[changes['N_Compte'].duplicated()==True]['N_Compte'].tolist()
double=changes[changes['N_Compte'].isin(cpt_double)]
print(double)
change_new=double[(double["version"]=="new")]
change_old=double[(double["version"]=="old")]
print(change_new)
print(change_old)
change_new=change_new.drop(["version"],axis=1)
change_old=change_old.drop(["version"],axis=1)
change_new.set_index("N_Compte",inplace=True)
change_old.set_index("N_Compte",inplace=True)
df_all_changes=pd.concat([change_old,change_new],axis='columns',keys=['old','new'],join='outer')
df_all_changes=df_all_changes.swaplevel(axis='columns')[change_new.columns[0:]]
print(df_all_changes)
```

**This is the result I need**
[image: result I need]

Comment: provide a reproducible example and attach the code as text rather than as image

Comment: `df = df.loc[df["old"] != df["new"]]`

Comment: Hi Thank you for noticing me, sorry about that, I edited but I am not sure if its clear, let me know if i need to improve my question